# How do you hold all the items of a collectionView in place when the device rotates without locking the device in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uiinterfaceorientation

I would like to build a collectionView that holds all the cells in place when the user rotates the device without locking the device's orientation into portrait mode. I have tried invalidating the layout but to no avail. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Set the Supported interface orientations to portrait only in your info.plist?

Comment: @AshleyMills I would like to still allow the app to detect when it is in landscape mode as well

Comment: You have other screens that need to work in both orientations?

Comment: @AshleyMills In a sense yes I would like them to detect when they are in a landscape mode but I would not like for the screens to rotate or any items on the screen of the collectionView to move when the rotation occurs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - why do you want to know if the device is in landscape orientation if the screens aren't rotating?

Comment: @AshleyMills one of the screens is a camera built from AVFoundation if the orientation is landscape I would like to take a landscape photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, that you want to keep all screens in portrait orientation, but know if the device is in landscape orientation without rotating the interface (for a camera screen), you should…

- set **Supported interface orientations** to **portrait** in `your info.plist`
- detect the device orientation using `CMMotionManager`…

  ```
  let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
  var currentOrientation = UIDeviceOrientation.portrait

  func montiorOrientation() {
      motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue()) { data, error in
          if let error = error {
              print("CM orientation error - \(error)")
              return
          }
          let acceleration = data!.acceleration

          let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = fabs(acceleration.y) < fabs(acceleration.x) ?
              (acceleration.x > 0 ? .landscapeRight : .landscapeLeft) :
              (acceleration.y > 0 ? self.currentOrientation : .portrait) // Ignore portraitUpsideDown

          if orientation != self.currentOrientation {
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.currentOrientation = orientation
              }
          }

      }
  }
  ```